# syntax error in join when trying to join with a subquery

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, ado

Using VBA, I want join a selection of one table to another, based on some conditions. The solution is probably simple, but I just can't find the error.  I get a Runtime Error -2147217900 (80040e14) "Syntax-Error in join operation".

```
SELECT *
FROM [target$] AS Ziel
LEFT JOIN
          (
                 SELECT *
                 FROM   [source$]
                 WHERE  [Zust].[FS] = 3
                 AND    Year([Zust].[DATUM_1A])=2018 as Zust)
ON        (
                    [Ziel].[Lage] = [Zust].[LAGE]
          AND       ((
                                        [Zust].[BKM] < [Zust].[VKM]
                              AND       [Ziel].[MitteBetrKm] <= [Zust].[VKM]
                              AND       [Ziel].[MitteBetrKm] > [Zust].[BKM])
                    OR        (
                                        [Zust].[BKM] > [Zust].[VKM]
                              AND       [Ziel].[MitteBetrKm] >= [Zust].[VKM]
                              AND       [Ziel].[MitteBetrKm] < [Zust].[BKM])))
WHERE     [Ziel].[MitteBetrKm] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY  [Ziel].[VonKm]
```

Comment: MS Access does not support inequalities with outer joins.  That is why you should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what such logic should be doing.

Comment: Simplyfying to the relevant columns, in the target sheet, I have a "MitteBetrKm", and a "Lage" column. In the source sheet, I have "BKM", "VKM", "DATUM_1A", "FS", "Lage" and other columns whose content I want in the result. For each row in the target sheet, I want the corresponding data from the source sheet, when the year of the "DATUM_1A" column is 2018, when "Lage" matches "Lage" in the target sheet, and when "MitteBetrKm" is between "VKM" and "BKM". I don't have data for all rows of the target sheet, and want to keep the rows for which I have no data in the source sheet.